# Vlookup - regarding the physical location of value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I want to use `vlookup` to find a certain value and I already have this formula. The thing is, now what formula do I need to use to get the location of the above value which I have in the vlookup formula?

By location I mean the cell location, such as `A5` or `B7`.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You forgot to share the formula you already have.  You can edit your post to include it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the `MATCH()` function instead. It will return the relative position of an item in an array which you can then provide as input for the `INDEX()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX()` seems to have changed over the years. Now I have to use the following to get the address:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(D1,A1:A6,0),1))
```

It is not a "real" address in that it does not directly address anything, it's just a text string. But `INDIRECT()` can fix that. (Of course, if one wanted that, one would need only use the `INDEX/MATCH`.)

Back then, or, shall I say "once upon a time," one just needed to do two copies of the `INDEX()` with a colon between them, like so:

```
=INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(D1,A1:A6,0),1):INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(D1,A1:A6,0),1)
```

and the address would be the result. Ah well.